# How do I setup the reset password function on Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have this error: "The view file does not exist: /var/www/html/myproject/frontend/views/common/mail/passwordResetToken-html.php"

This is the code located at frontend/models/PasswordResetRequestForm

```
return Yii::$app
    ->mailer
    ->compose(
        ['html' => '/common/mail/passwordResetToken-html', 
         'text' => '/common/mail/passwordResetToken-text'],
        ['user' => $user]
    )
    ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => Yii::$app->name . ' robot'])
    ->setTo($this->email)
    ->setSubject('Password reset for ' . Yii::$app->name)
    ->send();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be you have the wrong path for common mail  try

```
return Yii::$app
    ->mailer
    ->compose(
        ['html' => '@common/mail/passwordResetToken-html', 
         'text' => '@common/mail/passwordResetToken-text'],
        ['user' => $user]
    )
    ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => Yii::$app->name . ' robot'])
    ->setTo($this->email)
    ->setSubject('Password reset for ' . Yii::$app->name)
    ->send();
```

And over all check if your main.php or main-local you have

```
 'components' => [
    .....
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail', //  <<<<----------- this  entry  
         ....
        ......
        'transport' => [
           ....
        ],
    ],
  ],
```

Comment: Now I have this error: "The view file does not exist: /var/www/html/myproject/frontend/mail/layouts/html.php"

Comment: check in  your common/config   main.php or main-local.php for the component  mailer  and update  your question with this configuration

Comment: @JanBeeck   add the view path  like i have update my answer

Comment: @JanBeeck  i think you can restore the original  '/common/mail/password...   path ... let me know

Comment: It didn't work with  '/common/mail/passwordResetToken-html ', however it worked with '@common/mail/passwordResetToken-html'